# Fastest way to parse byte array?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently trying to parse an XML string to get various datapoints. My code below works but is eating up a ton of CPU usage so I want to optimize it anyway possible.

```
public static List<Purchase> ParsePurchases(Profile profile, byte[] data)
{
    // Parse the profile XML and extract purchases
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            // read the data into a string
            var xmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // create the DOM over it
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

            var purchaseElements = doc.GetElementsByTagName("purchase");
            List<Purchase> purchases = new List<Purchase>();
            for(var e = 0; e < purchaseElements.Count; e++)
            {
                var ele = (XmlElement)purchaseElements[e];
                    purchases.Add(
                     new Purchase(
                        profile,
                        Int32.Parse(ele.GetAttribute("id")),
                        Int32.Parse(((XmlElement)ele.GetElementsByTagName("price")[0]).InnerText),
                        Int32.Parse(((XmlElement)ele.GetElementsByTagName("quantity")[0]).InnerText),
                        ((XmlElement)ele.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0]).InnerText
                        ));


            }

            return purchases;
        }
    }
}
```

My LoadXml call is eating up the most CPU usage, around 44%, and my ReadToEnd call is eating up another 22%. Any ideas of how to optimize this?

Comment: Why bother with a `Stream` when you already have a `byte[]`? Why not simply call `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)`?

Comment: You might be able to reduce the parsing-load by adopting a streaming approach: [This (ancient, but still relevant) article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xmlteam/2007/03/24/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-2/) might help you rethink this.

Comment: What makes you think `data` is UTF-8? Is it coming from a file or network? If so, you should be using `XmlReader.Create`, which streams the input.

Comment: I went ahead and took your advice and invoked that call and it seems to have helped a great bit, but CPU usage is still fairly high. Thanks @DanWilson

Comment: @spender reading into that article now

Comment: You mention "faster" and "CPU usage" but there are different approaches for optimizing toward those goals. What's your ultimate goal? I don't typically optimize for low CPU usage. Unless you're pegging the CPU then I wouldn't worry.

Comment: @DanWilson my cpu usage will rise up to ~95% usage and is caused by this function, and I've been having some blocked requests due to CPU performance blocking other requests.

Comment: Relevant: [Interpreting CPU Utilization](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/winserverperformance/2009/08/06/interpreting-cpu-utilization-for-performance-analysis/)